# ARKit: Reproducing the Project Point function

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I'm attempting to reproduce the ARCamera's project point function, but for some reason the values are not matching up properly. I am taking the ARCamera's projection matrix and view matrix and applying basic CG perspective transform math, (PV) * p, but the NDC values do not match the pixel values given from the ARCamera's project point function. Any ideas? Am I forgetting something?

Some more detail:

Basically, I'm trying to take an ARFrame a the click of a button, and then trying to replicate the functionality of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923538-projectpoint. I'm attempting to do this with https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2921672-viewmatrix, making sure all of the inputs match for both parts. CG size is used to transform the coordinates from NDC space to image space.

EDIT: Solution found, check comments below.

Comment: There's not enough detail in your question to say. But one thing to look into might be the difference between the camera image's aspect ratio and that of the view.

Comment: I've added some more detail regarding the documentation of what I'm using. Checking the aspect ratio is a good idea, but I'd be surprised if the internal projectionMatrix of the ARCamera is different than what's used in the projectPoint function.

Comment: Have you made any progress at this? Is the internal projectionMatrix of the ARCamera different than what's used in the projectPoint function?

Comment: Yes! If you just take camera.projectionMatrix you will get the wrong matrix depending on your viewport orientation, you need to use camera.projectionMatrix(for:UIInterfaceOrientation, viewportSize:CGSize, zNear: float, zFar: float). For some reason they give you access to something that doesn't update properly.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! Be sure to post it as an answer so other folks can easily find it.

Comment: BTW, judging by the docs for [`projectionMatrix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix) vs [`projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrix), it looks like the former knows nothing about interface orientation, so it assumes you're looking for projection to an NDC space that's aligned with the native sensor orientation of the camera.

Comment: Hmm, reading the projectionMatrix documentation makes it seem like it automatically handles orientation, but in practice it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Hi @Mozahler! Did you still keep working on that? I tried to work out the math but has no luck,,,

Comment: Check out this link. I used this library for my puzzle app "Nosie" in the app store. You can learn a ton from playing with it. https://github.com/ebay/HeadGazeLib

Comment: Hi @Mozahler! Thanks for the response! I am reading https://github.com/eBay/HeadGazeLib/blob/master/HeadGazeLib/UIHeadGazeView.swift :(( I am a bit lost honestly.. I think I want to ask in terms of reproducing project point from ARCamera, does `projection matrix *view matrix* transform matrix*` *3D points will help you to transform 3D point to 2D image point? I am not quite getting in as I am doing the math at the moment...

Comment: tbh I got into computers so they could do my math for me! My recommendation: Connect your phone via cable to your mac.  Build the simplest possible test example and run under the debugger with breakpoints anywhere you're not 100% sure.   Change the code, rerun and understand what changed and why.

Comment: Hi @Mozahler Thanks for the response! How would you understand this if can help me out here. I am doing the math in Matlab to check the concept here. So I took the 3D points (x,y,z,w) and set w=1 so its 4x1. And I combine `projection matrix *view matrix* transform matrix` to be a 4x4. The final result of the combined matrix * 3D point will give 4x1. These m11,m22,m33,m44 have 4 components.... how can we get the image coordinate of x and y?

Comment: @Mozahler and the final result of m11,m22,m33,m44 is something like this as an example:  `-0.0807, -0.0543 ,-1.0494, 0`. These numbers do not look like image coordinates and so I was not sure if I did it correctly based on this post and your GitHub suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be [projection_matrix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2887458-projectionmatrix) sometimes does not correctly find the device orientation. The correct approach is to use [projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2923539-projectionmatrix).