# ARKit - Simulating the change of ARCamera

Tags: scenekit, arkit

I am interested in simulating the projection of the corners of an `SCNPlane` from different positions and orientations of `ARCamera`.

As expected, ARKit doesn't allow us to manipulate the position and orientation of the ARCamera. This means that I need to capture the transform of the camera with respect to the world, manipulate it (translate and/or rotate) and then use the intrinsic matrix to get the projected point on the image plane.

The question is, how can I simulate different ARCamera poses? How would you reproduce the projections to the image plane by relying on the ARCamera pose?

**Approach 1**

`K*C*P`, where `K` is the intrinsic matrix, `C` the transform of the camera with respect to the world and  `P` is the point we want to project expressed in world coordinates. I am surprised to see that this approach doesn't work - I am calling the native function `projectPoint` and then calling my custom approach and I am not getting the same results.

```
static func projectPointCustom(_ point: SCNVector3, sceneView: ARSCNView) -> SCNVector3 {
        var p = SCNVector3()
        guard let camera = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera else { return SCNVector3()}
        let pCam = camera.transform * simd_float4(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), Float(point.z), 1.0)

        print("pCam = \(pCam)")
        p = SCNVector3(pCam.x/pCam.w, pCam.y/pCam.w, pCam.z/pCam.w)
        let res2 = camera.intrinsics * simd_float3(p)

        p = SCNVector3(res2)
        // let res = camera.projectionMatrix(for: .portrait, viewportSize: sceneView.bounds.size, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000.0) * simd_float4(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), Float(point.z), 1.0)
        // p = SCNVector3(res.x, res.y, res.z)
        return p
    }
```

**Approach 2**

Using `viewMatrix` - per Apple's documentation, `viewMatrix` returns a transform matrix for converting from world space to camera space. So, convert point `P` to camera space, then use intrinsics to see where it hits in the image plane. Also doesn't work.

```
static func projectPointCustom(_ point: SCNVector3, sceneView: ARSCNView) -> SCNVector3 {
        var p = SCNVector3()
        guard let camera = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera else { return SCNVector3()}
        let pCam = camera.viewMatrix(for: .portrait) * simd_float4(Float(point.x), Float(point.y), Float(point.z), 1.0)

        print("pCam = \(pCam)")
        p = SCNVector3(pCam.x/pCam.w, pCam.y/pCam.w, pCam.z/pCam.w)
        let res2 = camera.intrinsics * simd_float3(p)
        //let res2 = simd_float3(p)
        p = SCNVector3(res2)
        return p
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need the camera's intrinsic matrix for what you are trying to do, it should be accounted for in the camera's projection matrix. A multiplication of the `viewMatrix` with the result of camera's `projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar)` should get you to normalized device coordinates, and then using image size to get to image coordinates.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957310/arkit-reproducing-the-project-point-function?rq=1

Comment: Hey @oneiros were you able to figure out `projectionMatrix(for:viewportSize:zNear:zFar)`? I tried to use `sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.projectionMatrix` to access projection matrix but it stays constant throughout, but the projection matrix is not changing.Is projection matrix in arkit/scenekit is constant?

Comment: Hi @Michael. I was trying to use `sceneView.session.currentFrame!.camera.projectionMatrix` to access projection matrix but it stays constant throughout. Is projection matrix in arkit/scenekit is constant?

Comment: @swiftlearneer I think the projectionMatrix is intended to stay constant, as it's the matrix that converts your points from 3d camera space onto 2d image. Once your points are in 3d space relative to camera (i.e. view space), it's a constant projection based on camera and projection properties to convert those to 2d points.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the response! However, but each frame (for the 3D points) that I am capturing, I am expecting that a changing matrix should be used to do the conversion rather than a constant projection matrix?

Comment: Hi @oneiros did you figure out the math?

Comment: @swiftlearneer what exactly are you trying to achieve? Like converting what to what?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I am trying to convert 3D mesh point to 2D image point